# Python Parent Class Instance Variables

Tags: python

I have a parent class named `parent` and its like this:

```
class parent(object):

    def __init__(self,p1,p2):
        super(parent,self).__init__()
        self.p1= p1
        self.p2= p2
```

I have another child class that looks like the following:

```
class child(parent):

    def __init__(self,p1,p2,p3):
        super(child,self).__init__()
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3
```

This child class has one extra instance variable called `p3`. What I am trying to do is have the ability to create objects with parameters. These parameters are used to update both the inherited variables `p1 & p2` of class `parent` and its own instance variables `p3`. But when I run the above, I get error:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = parent('p1_parent','p2_parent')


    p2 = child('p1_child','p1_child','p1_child')
```

error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Why are you calling `super(Event, self)` when the class isn't `Event`? `Event` doesn't even appear in the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass `p1` and `p2` to the parent class constructor:

```
super(child, self).__init__(p1, p2)
```

Example:

```
class parent(object):
    def __init__(self,p1,p2):
        super(parent, self).__init__()
        self.p1= p1
        self.p2= p2

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self,p1,p2,p3):
        super(child,self).__init__(p1, p2)
        self.p3 = p3


child1 = child(1,2,3)
print child1.p1, child1.p2, child1.p3
```

prints: `1 2 3`

Comment: if so do I still need to the lines `self.p1 = p1` and `self.p2 = p2` or with your answer it will automatically fill those values in?

Comment: @user1234440 nope, you don't need `self.p1 = p1` and `self.p2 = p2`.

Comment: @alecxe How many instance variables does the child class have? 1 (p3) or 3 (p1,p2,p3)?